# When multiplying large positive numbers, why is the result negative?

Tags: c, linux

Here is the snippets of my code and the output. Suggest the reason behind a negative result when large positive numbers are multiplied?

```
int printM(int v)
{
     int g=v+5;
     g=g*3344564*452346;
     printf("The value of g is %d\n",g);
     return g;
}
int main()
{
    int f=0;
    int a=45;
    a=a+334;
    a=a+534534;
    a=a+939;
    a=a+45345654645;
    f=printM(a);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
pravesh@pravesh-Aspire-4552:~/Desktop/c_d$ gcc -g linked_list.c 
pravesh@pravesh-Aspire-4552:~/Desktop/c_d$ ./a.out 
The value of g is -377042000
```

`

Comment: What is the range of `signed int`?....

Comment: integer overflow (which is undefined behavior on signed integers). Grab a good book and maybe start to learn by reading it. Somewhere on SO is a list of good books.

Comment: even if i put signed , then also the result is same

Answer (score 1):

What you end up with when overflowing an `int` is *undefined behaviour*. `INT_MAX` is defined to be the largest value that an `int` can represent on your platform.

Note that overflowing an `unsigned` is well defined: it wraps around modulo `UINT_MAX + 1`.

(For what it's worth, what's *probably* happening in your case is that the `int` is wrapping around in exactly the same way as it would do if the memory is interpreted as an `unsigned`).

Comment: " it wraps around modulo 2N where N is the number of bits in the unsigned type." - not exactly. There can be padding bits. Better to say it wraps modulo `UINT_MAX + 1`